# Minimising Critical path over all permutations

Tags: permutation, minimize

There are suppose 6 tasks that are to be done [1 2 3 4 5 6]. Critical path method is done to find the critical path which is the longest path required to finish the job for one permuted task. Similarly there are 6! ways to find paths and hence 6! critical paths. Now, I have to minimise and find the path which is minimum critical using another approach. It is like [Min Max critical path over all P]. What could be possible way of solving this using a mathematical formulation

Comment: If this is a math question, why don't you try http://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: The algorithms are there critical path method and tsp but how to combine them. But thanks I will ask in that as well